# how to populated a combobox in wince

Tags: c++, windows-ce, win32gui

I tried to populated a combo box on a DIALOG  with following code:

```
TCHAR szTmp[64];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
  wsprintf(szTmp, TEXT("Item %d"), i);
  SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_COMBO,CB_INSERTSTRING, (WPARAM)i, (LPARAM)szTmp);     
}
  SendDlgItemMessage(hBaudRate, IDC_COMBO, CB_SETCURSEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
```

That did not work. Please let know what I am missing.

Comment: Try changing the first `SendDlgItemMessage` call to: `l = SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_COMBO,CB_INSERTSTRING, (WPARAM)i, (LPARAM)szTmp);` to see if an error is returned (`l` should be declared as type `LONG`

Answer (score 0):

If both calls to `SendDlgItemMessage()` are operating on the same ComboBox, then `hwnd` should be changed to `hBaudRate`, or vice versa.

Also, the `WPARAM` of the `CB_INSERTSTRING` message should be changed to `-1`, or else use `CB_ADDSTRING` instead.

Comment: should I call those two lines from WM_INITDIALOG?  what I intend to do is to create a popup with two comboboxes